# Why are all requests to ECS container going to only 1 (of 2) EC2 instances in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, amazon-ecs

In AWS, I have an ECS cluster that contains a service that has 2 EC2 instances. I sent 3 separate API requests to this service, each should take about an hour to run at 100% capacity. I sent the requests a couple minutes apart. They all went to the same instance and left the other open. Here's a graph of CPU utilization[image: CPU Utilization for EC2 Instances] Here's an image of my Service CPU Utilization. It is not using all it's bandwidth: [image: Service CPU Utilization] What am I missing? Why won't requests go to the second EC2 instance

Comment: You need to provide more information. Are these behind a load balancer?

Comment: @MarkB i dont think i have a load balancer i just thought it would balance itself if one was CPU 100%? I also just realized the API returns 200 immediately, then continues working async, so maybe that’s the issue?

Comment: There is nothing about this that will "balance itself". You just have 2 Docker containers running, and it sounds like you are sending all the requests directly to one, without even using the other one in any way. A load balancer may have helped some, but it wouldn't have kept things balanced 100%. I would suggest you look into queueing the requests in SQS instead of sending them directly to your instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `ALB` will not perfectly Round-Robin between two instances. If you sent `100` requests, `100` times, then on average each instance would receive `50` requests each, but most of the time it won't be `50` exactly for each backend.

For a long running task like this it is preferable to use something else such as `SQS`, whereby each container will only process `x` messages at a time (most of the time you'd want `x=1`). Each instance can then poll `SQS` for the work, and wont take more work whilst it is busy.

You will receive other benefits too such as being able to see how long a message is taking to finish, and error handling capabilities to account for timeouts or if a server were to die whilst it is doing work.